# How do I add dynamic urls to each loaded post in PHP and MYSQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, url

Ok so I have a mysql database that contains pictures and text. I am able to load multiple pictures on the page, like an gallery. But I want to make each picture to have a url so when shared on social networks that plugin can detect each picture individually. So for example code:

```
<div id="mainframe" class="galleryPic">
  <div class="pic">
   <img src="'.$example.'"/>
  </div>
    <div class="social network plugins">Social Button</div>
</div>
```

How do I make each gallery loaded with each having a different url?
So it would look like this url:

```
www.example.com/something/id?=whatever/
```

Comment: $_GET['id'] will contain 'whatever' in this case, so check if the $_GET['id'] is > 0, then show the picture with the ID? Also remember to filter the data (in this case check if its int i suppose)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand, you could consider to use RewriteMod / RewriteRules in apache .htaccess to handle with urls and convert a URL like:

```
www.example.com/something/whatever/id/
```

to

```
www.exemple.com/something.php?whatever=id
```

So, in the php script you can get the whatever param and submit it to your mysql database.

A very simple RewriteRule:

```
RewriteRule ^news/(.*?)$ content.php?content=read-news&news=$1 [NC]
```

where **$1** represents **(.*?)**, or everythig after **/**

Rewrite documentation: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are asking for.  Its from my site, I have removed `class` attributes and surrounding `divs` etc  to keep it simple.

```
<a title='Click to See Detail'href="app_profile.php?id=$imageid">
  <span style="background-image:url(folder/$imageid.jpg);">
  </span>
</a>
```

Note that I use background image, it allows me to put sprites on top easier.  It is also a bit more work for someone to save the image.